# How to record commands history logs of the CentOS?

Tags: centos, logs

The same thing I had tried on Ubuntu by [following this](http://www.technowise.in/2016/12/log-ec2-bashlinux-commands-to.html).

1. Modify the `/etc/bash.bashrc`
2. Append below line the end of that file

   ```
   export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
   ```
3. Create a new file `/etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf`
4. Add the line to the file

   ```
   local6.*    /var/log/commands.log
   ```
5. Add line to the file `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`

   ```
   /var/log/commands.log
   ```
6. Restart the Rsyslog

sudo service rsyslog restart

Output on Ubuntu:

```
Feb 2 05:17:58 ip-172-31-21-42 ubuntu: ubuntu [1785]: su - jawad [0]
Feb 2 05:17:58 ip-172-31-21-42 ubuntu: ubuntu [1785]: su - jawad [0]
Feb 2 05:18:38 ip-172-31-21-42 ubuntu: root [1817]: service awslogs restart [0]
Feb 2 05:18:56 ip-172-31-21-42 ubuntu: message repeated 2 times: [ root [1817]: service awslogs restart [0]]
Feb 2 05:20:29 ip-172-31-21-42 ubuntu: root [1817]: service awslogs restart [0]
Feb 2 05:20:41 ip-172-31-21-42 ubuntu: root [1817]: vi /etc/passwd [0]
Feb 2 05:20:52 ip-172-31-21-42 ubuntu: root [1817]: service rsyslog restart [0]
```

in Red Hat Linux is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been logging the `bash` commands as the command below, and it has been working well for years:

```
readonly PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a >(logger -t "commandlog $USER[$PWD] $SSH_CONNECTION")'
```

The `readonly` directive prevents users from changing it.